# How to draw a circle inside a path on canvas in Android

Tags: android, android-canvas

I want to draw a circle inside a path on canvas. To draw a circle, center co-ordinates and radius are required.

How can I calculate the center co-ordinates and radius for a circle inside a path?

Comment: Could you show us a picture of what you want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path which you have created might be of irregular shape,it may not contain circle properly,anyways,
You can create a `RectF` from the `Path` and then get the center point of the `RectF`,

```
    RectF mRectF = new RectF(); 
    mOverlayPath.computeBounds(mRectF, true);//here, mOverlayPath is your path
    float cX = mRectF.centerX();
    float cY = mRectF.centerY();
```

Comment: Thanks Mehul. Its working.
I would like to mention that you mixed the REGION and RECTF declaration in first line.

Comment: @Gaurav: I'm glad to be helpful. I have completely removed `Region` as it is not required for your task.